# Struts2 same namespaces in different struts.xml files

Tags: struts2, struts2-namespace

Is it possible to use same namespace in different struts.xml files?. I know that we can use different namespaces. The problem is, i have so many actions in my configuration file. I just want to split up inorder to manage easily. But if i use different namespace for each file, i have to modify the namespace mentioned everywhere(JSPs).

For ex.

I want to use **namespace="/"** in all my struts.xml files.

I hope you understand what I am coming to say. Is this possible or any other relevant easy method to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely can use multiple packages with same namespace. Just remember packages cannot have same names. You also need to include them all in your main struts.xml like:

```
<include file="path to your config files"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response doctrey. Will try that out.

Answer (score 0):

```
<struts>

    <!-- Other information goes here -->     
    <include file = "Administrator-Config.xml"/>
    <include file = "CustomerConfig.xml"/>
    <include file = "EmployerConfig.xml"/>  
    <!-- Other information goes here -->

</struts>
```